# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'"

Tags: python, modulenotfounderror

[image: Screenshot of Error]
Why the error occurs after installing pandas?

Comment: have you installed pandas?

Answer (score 0):

if you are in virtual environment, make sure you are in that environment :) 
[image]

Comment: My environment is python3